# When last row in section of UITableView with Core Data is moved -> NSRangeException

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data

Hi: Moving rows between sections in Core Data backed UITableView works quite fine after I've implemented a 'userDrivenChange' check in 'controllerDidChangeContent:', as mentioned in the apple docs. 
But only when moving the last row of a section to another section I get a **NSRangeException**. There is obviously a problem when sections get empty. How could I handle that the best way?

Comment: Can you provide some code explaining what you are doing now?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the `-controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` method?  If not, that may look something like this:

```
-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {     
    switch(type) {          
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```